# Is it possible to implement Geofencing in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geofencing

We were planning to develop an application using Openlayers, which can display the incoming GPS signals as markers and create alerts , if the markers( positions) are outside a particular zone.

Is this possible through Openlayers code ? or do we have to use something JSTS Topology suite with Openlayers ?

Comment: Please check following link https://github.com/santiago/geofencing

Comment: Displaying the markers seems like no problem. What do you need the alerts to do? That may be limited by what is achievable with Javascript in a typical browser setting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  However you have a whole bunch of other issues to resolve.  But it is possible with a simple `intersects` calculation of 2 geometries.

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.intersects

Overall, the problem I see with your approach is that it requires a client-side GUI and someone looking at it to trigger a geofencing alert.  That should *probably* be done on the server side and sent out as email and/or made available to the client on some polled ajax request.  But...what you asked for is possible.